# System admin password not working

Tags: security, password, privacy, sudo, administrator

I have a 2019 Macbook Pro, Ventura. Recently, I've noticed that my system password (I am the only user, and I checked in Users & Groups) doesn't work to change my Privacy and Security settings. I just reset it (to the same thing albeit) and tried again, and it does not work. This is for all applications, changing Privacy and Security settings. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is this a problem throughout System Settings, or is it just related to MS Teams?  And I am not clear as to whether a) your password is not accepted, or b) the password is accepted but the change doesn't happen.

Comment: Password is not accepted. For anything at all. I will modify.

Comment: I am the main user on my Mac, so I have the admin account (root level access) and my user account (user level access), other users get user level as well. Have always set up accounts like this as it reduces errors by people deleting/changing the wrong thing. Perhaps you should consider it for the future. Also,  try a complete system reinstall and do a backup first.

Comment: You mean reinstall my OS? @SolarMike

Comment: I've also lost functionality like Touch ID for an app called Duo Mobile in Google Chrome. I'm not sure if it's related.

Comment: Password not accepted for anything. Ouch! I always like to have a second admin user in case of circumstances like this. Looks horribly like a complete reinstall.

Comment: Would I lose my application information with a complete reinstall @Gilby ?

Comment: Yes. By complete reinstall, I would be booting to recovery, erasing the disk and installing macOS followed by Migration Assistant to recover just data files from Time Machine. Not applications and settings. Then reinstall apps and get everything working. Long and tedious. But don't rush into that. Someone may suggest something easier.

Comment: I just did a restart and everything works again. Really weird. Worries me about compromised password security